# What is the recommended resource to refer to for syntax, usage and information about commands for an application?

Tags: command-line, command, man

What is the recommended resource to refer to for syntax, usage and information about commands for an application? I am currently trying to decide between `command help` (assuming that `command` has a `help`) or `man command`.

Comment: Read the source, Luke.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard; some combination of `man command`, `info command | less`, `command -h`, `command --help`, `command -help` (ugh, Java), looking around for a README, altagoobingleduckgoing, etc. must be used depending on the command and how good the vendor is about writing documentation (OpenBSD is very good in this regard, others well maybe yeah about that).

Warning! Trying random flags as `root` is a Very Bad Idea, as I've had to fix the hostname on Solaris boxes where some Linux admin had run `hostname -f` and thus set all the Solaris hostnames to `-f`.

Another option is to dig around in packages or ports for `doc` or such type directories, which will vary by the port or package system in question:

```
$ port contents nasm | egrep 'man|doc'
  /opt/local/share/man/man1/ldrdf.1.gz
  /opt/local/share/man/man1/nasm.1.gz
  ...

$ rpm -ql mutt | grep manual
/usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.21/manual.html
/usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.21/manual.txt
```

(etc)